# Python / opencv getting ret, frame from .read() when using self

Tags: python, opencv

I hope you understand what I am asking for her. I have just started learning python and opencv, so If my question seems strange then that's probably the cause :-)

I am trying to create a class in python to activate my camera. But I am struggling to get two values from the read() function when using *self*.

```
Normally you would just use:
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

I just want to get the boolean return value from ret as well as frame from the class as well.

```
class Camera:

def __init__(self):
    self.video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(device)


    # if capture failed to open, try to open again
    if not self.video_capture.isOpened():
        self.video_capture.open(device)

    self.ret ,self.current_frame = self.video_capture.read()[1]

    self.current_height = int(self.video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# create thread for capturing images
def start(self) -> object:
    Thread(target=self._update_frame, args=()).start()

def _update_frame(self):
    while (True):
        self.current_frame = self.video_capture.read()[1]

# get the current frame
def get_current_frame(self):
    return self.current_frame

# get return 0 or 1 from cap.read()
def get_ret(self):
    return self.retd()
```

How can i get both ret and frame from self.video_capture.read()?

I have tried to search for my answer. But when you don't really know what to exactly search for, It gets difficult finding anything.

Comment: have you tried `ret, self.current_frame = self.video_capture.read()`?

Comment: yes, I have tried that. Running that give me this error:

`ret ,self.current_frame = self.video_capture.read()[1]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: that looks weird, it should work, since read always return 2 values.... just to discard the obvious, do you have the correct identation in your code? in your question, you have wrong identation (`def __init__` should be some spaces to the right) maybe it is only while copying, but is better to discard problems. Also, what does the read function returns inside the `__init__` method? the image? the bool value? `None`?

Comment: Added the rest of the class, maybe you can make some more sense of what I am trying then. Tried changing ret to self.ret but same result

In my main .py file where I use this class, I call the get() function using `img = kamera.get_current_frame()` but that does not work when using ret

Comment: `self.video_capture.read()[1]` <--- there is a [1] there... which only will get the frame value, thus the error of too many values to unpack

Comment: ahh, Is that what that means. Now It works, thank you :-)

Comment: No problem I will put it as answer for future readers to find the solution faster

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
self.ret ,self.current_frame = self.video_capture.read()[1]
```

Basically you are accessing one value  using `[1]` of the two values returned by `read()`. To obtain both values just remove it.

```
self.ret ,self.current_frame = self.video_capture.read()
```

If you are only interested in one value it is ok to use the `[1]`